# How do I make sure my shapes "points" to the correct macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy one sheet to a completely new workbook. I use this code below for this. My problem is, that this sheet contains a couple of shapes with assigned macros. In the new workbook these asigned macros "points" to the macros of the old workbook. I would need the new workbook to include it's own macros and point to themselves. I can solve the problem by just pressing assign macro on the shapes and choosing the correct ones. (The macro copies to the new workbook, but the shapes still "points" to the old workbook's macros)

```
sheettocopy = Range("EU10").Value
Worksheets(sheettocopy).Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]If your macro is created at the sheet, copying the sheet to new workbook will point to new workbook macro.

Comment: no it doesn't. If I were to rightclick on the shape with the macros(in the new workbook) and then press "assign macro" I can see that the currently assigned macro is "'name of old workbook.xlsm'sheet4.macroname" and not the new one. It might have something to do with how im copying the sheet to a new workbook(see code above)

Comment: what you are showing with your screenpicks has nothing to do with "pointing". Yes the macro will be copied into "the same place" in the new workbook as it was before. But the shape with the assigned macro will not "point" to the macro in its own sheet but rather at the macro in the "same" sheet in the old workbook.

Comment: read the answer by Dorian and you might understand what I mean!

Comment: Nevermind. As long as it is solved.

Comment: nevertheless, Thank you for at least trying to help me :)